# Do Test Flight public link require tester to have Test Flight account

Tags: ios, iphone, testflight

I have generated a public link for external tester. My client who is also my external tester do not have iTunes Connect account. So it is possible for my client to test the app without creating a iTunes Connect account?

Answer (score 0):

When you install the TestFlight application in your device it will automatically link with your apple account.

yes you can test without iTunes Connect account